# How can I omit a variable from a model when calling a PUT (edit) endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ASP.NET WEB API 2 service that deals with various objects.  We use this service to do basic CRUD functions.  They're all pretty simple, but I am running into an issue when attempting to edit an object.

I will let the code explain:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{companyId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCompanyByCompanyId([FromUri] int companyId)
    {
        // get company
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult AddCompany([FromBody] CompanyDto companyModel)
    {
        // Insert a company
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("{companyId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult UpdateCompany([FromUri] int companyId, [FromBody] Company companyModel)
    {
        // Update the company
    }
```

So what I have done is created Company and CompanyDto models.  The only difference between the two is that CompanyDto does not contain an id.  This is so that we can post the object and let the database tell us what the id will be.

After we have created our company object, we now have our Id.  Now we want to edit this object.  We pass in the full Company object to the PUT method and let it overwrite all the values.  However, there is one variable/attribute in the Company model that we are not allowed to update.  Obviously, I can just omit it from being passed to the database in the repository layer.  However, I do not want to confuse consumers of this service.  I want to only expose the parameters that are required or editable.  How can we do this?

Here are the Company and CompanyDto models for reference:

```
public class Company
{
    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int DataCenterId { get; set; }
 }

 public class CompanyDto
 {
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int DataCenterId { get; set; }
 }
```

See, when we POST the CompanyDto, we provide the DataCenterId, but when we edit the Company object, we should not be allowed to edit the DataCenterId.  When we GET the Company object, we should receive all 3 attributes.  Do I need to make a 3rd model to achieve this, or is there a data annotation that can help me with this?  We are not using EF by the way.  We have our own in house ORM solution.

Comment: Can you show the code where you're actually editing the model and then saving it?

Comment: I have not put together that code yet.  However, the way it works is there will be a hashtable of parameters and that gets passed to a stored procedure.  I can just omit the variable in that hashtable, but the data contract for the endpoints will still contain it and that is what I am ultimately trying to avoid.

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like you need a bit more flexibility in the ORM so that you can update on a per field basis

Comment: Yea, I agree, our in house ORM is not the best solution.  It does have some advantages that keep us using it though.

Comment: I believe you're going to need a new model then.

Comment: Yea I just did that.  I built a Company data transfer object to be used for POSTS so that we can provide a CompanyName and DataCenterId.  I created a regular Company return object so that we can retrieve CompanyId, CompanyName, and DataCenterId.  I also created a Company object that only contains the CompanyName since we cannot edit the other values.  Not the most elegant solution, but I think it will have to do for the meantime.

Comment: Yea I think the optimal solution is an update to the ORM but sometimes you have to work with what you have

Comment: Just for reference, I found some other people talking about the same issue.  They seem to lean towards just ignoring the un-editable parameters when the model is passed in and just use the params that you need.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/208271/how-should-a-rest-api-handle-put-requests-to-partially-modifiable-resources

Comment: Right, maybe I misunderstood your description. My thinking was that you were unable to ignore the parameters because of the way the ORM and stored procedure worked. If you can ignore the parameters that is definitely a better solution

Answer (score 0):

To make the solution complete and for the auto generated help to be of utmost correctness, yes, you will have to make a third DTO-object which only includes those properties that the clients are actually allowed to edit. This is the only way to convey the correct message to the consumers using those URI:s you have.

If, however, you can and are willing to change the URI:s and if they happen to be of a more descriptive variety to your domain, I'd also suggest you think whether or not the company ID could reside in the URI itself. That way you'd get it out of the DTOs and you would not have to have different classes just for that.

Also, the PUT-method should take the CompanyDto object as the parameter, as the company ID is already provided in the URI. Otherwise, what does the user expect to happen, if the URI company ID is different than the one in the Company object in the request?

Do also take note, that you should not deliver these DTOs as such into the business logic layer, which I suspect you are now doing based on the Company object as the parameter of the PUT-method. Instead, the business layer should have another object defined and the WebAPI object should be mapped to that, including the IDs from the URI. This way a change into the underlying business layer DTO will not break the actual public API, which is the WebAPI.

We had a pretty nifty system in my previous company that I continue to use today, where we named all the incoming classes as request-classes, i.e. CompanyRequest, and all the outgoing classes as response-classes, i.e. CompanyResponse. This way the response can be enriched with, for instance, the name of the Data center, as it is almost always required when viewing the company entity. Then again, that name should not appear on the request objects, as that should not be edited through editing the company.